# Chrome auto create debug.log,how to stop it?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

Everytime I use the chrome to open a html file, then the chrome always create a debug.log file in same folder.
And the debug.log file has same content :

```
[0725/091558:ERROR:crash_report_database_win.cc(412)] unexpected header
```

My google-chrome-extension includes Adblock Plus, Chrono Download Manager.

How can I stop it? Thx.

Comment: Judging by the message, that file might have an incorrect header. Consider submitting a bugreport: https://bugs.chromium.org

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I already have solven the problem.

After I UNINSTALL the chrome, and REINSTALL the newest chrome, the problem is gone.

I think the problem is that the old chrome was broken.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem..Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: @Dwhitz Try the 64bit chrome, and reset your config.May help XD.

Answer (score 25):

Stop Chrome.

Delete (or just rename) the folder:

`%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Crashpad`

Restart Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't seem to permanently fix the issue, is a temporary fix for me.